# Set a specific cell width to column in XSSF Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi, xlsx, xssf

I am trying to export a table as xlsx using Apache POI XSSF. Table has 5 columns.

First row has title block merging 5 columns. In the second row, 5 headings for the table. Remaining rows are data. I want to set width of the column as max width of each heading blocks.

I tried `mySheet.autoSizeColumn(colnum)` and `mySheet.setColumnWidth(columnIndex, width)`. Problem with `AutosizeColumn`, it is returning the highest width of the data in all the rows. So If width of some data in table is more, table header width is becoming very large. 
And for the second one, `setColumnWidth`, I need to know width of the header cell so I can set it to the sheet. But how to find the width of a specific cell? Had no luck yet in figuring out how to do it. Any idea on how to that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest simple solution that I have used.

Use a condition and after writing the 2nd row, i.e. the heading row, use `AutosizeColumn()` it will change the cell width according to the header width and then the width will remain as it is.

Comment: Initially I was doing that in xls export. But when I use XSSF sheets, It dont seem to work. All the columns are getting hidden once the sheet is exported.